# Unit test Express middleware for change to request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I've written a simple Express middleware like so:

```
// middleware/addLocals.js
export default (req, res, next) => {
  req.locals = { foo: 'bar' };
  next();
};
```

Usage looks like:

```
// index.js
import express from 'express';
import addLocals from './middleware/addLocals';

const app = express();
app.get('/', [addLocals], getImage);
```

Is it possible to unit test the middleware with Jest to check that `req.locals` is correctly populated? I've seen examples of checking returned values, or possibly even running a test version of the server, but I can't find an example of the request object being checked for changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test middleware like this, you will have to separate concerns to accomplish this.

[Click for more information](https://medium.com/@morrissinger/unit-testing-express-middleware-behavior-in-ecmascript-2015-f1641ebb8040)